# How to change div background image in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ng-style

```
<div class="col m-2 image row"
    *ngFor="let aa of activiteAvenir" [ngStyle]="{'background-image':url(' +aa.image+ ')}"
     style=" background-repeat: no-repeat;   background-position: center; background- 
     size: cover; border-radius: 10px;">

</div>
```

> I tried a lot of things that didn't work  I really don't need it;
> urgently;
> In some cases the ng style was giving me [object object]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<div class="col m-2 image row"
    *ngFor="let aa of activiteAvenir" [ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url('+ aa.image +')'}"
     style=" background-repeat: no-repeat;   background-position: center; background- 
     size: cover; border-radius: 10px;">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but It does' nt work

Comment: Please check your variable aa.image

Comment: there is no problem with this variable
I already checked it

Comment: Please check again:
<div class="col m-2 image row" *ngFor="let aa of activiteAvenir" [ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url('+ aa.image +')'}">

</div>

Comment: use css in css file:
.image {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;   
  background-position: center; 
  background-size: cover; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}

Comment: may be it will be: <div class="col m-2 image row" *ngFor="let aa of activiteAvenir">
  <div [ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url('+ aa.image +')'}">

  </div>
</div>

Comment: I had already tried that